# QGIS Convert Polygon ZM to Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, convert

QGIS Convert Polygon ZM to Polygon

Received files that have Shape > PolygonZM I need to attach to Polygon. QGIS: Geometry >< Polygon (MultiPolygonZ)

I managed to get it to Geometry >>> Polygon (PolygonZ) with Vestor>Geomety Tools > Multipart to singleparts...

Then I changed with EXPORT > Save Features as > and marked in Layer Option > shp > Polygon and got >>> Polygon (MultiPolygon).

But I only need Polygon(Polygon).

Comment: Hi, i think that shapefile doesn't support Polygon geometries but MultiPolygon. Maybe your solution is to use another format to be able to store single part geometries?

Comment: Have you tried this tool: "Drop M/Z values
This algorithm can remove any measure (M) or Z values from input geometries."?